# R - accessing variable "name" inside a function

Tags: r

Having 2 or more file paths like below each to be read as separate data frames

```
file1 = ".data/abc_123.txt"
file2 = ".data/def_324.txt"
```

To enable batch reading, storing these filenames in to a vector 
    `filesVector = c(file1, file2)`

Inside the function used to batch read files, need to access the variable names that are in `filesVector`

```
csvToDF = function(filesVector){
  for(file in filesVector){ 
    # is there a way to extract variable names `file1` & `file2` inside here so as to create a dataframe with name of file as part of the variable for variable
    # in the above example data, it should create two data frames stored as variables `df_file1` and `df_file2`
    variable_name = read.csv(file)
  }
}
```

Comment: try `eval(substitute(file))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing it the way you do the variable names get lost. But as workaround you could name vector elements *before* you call the function:

```
names(filesVector) <- c("file1", "file2")
```

Now you should be able to access these inside the function simply with `names(filesVector)` or `names(filesVector[1])`.